# Media query for navbar doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

I'm making a navbar for my site following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g&t). While working on my mobile menu responsiveness I made a ".burger" class with three "bars" to represent the menu. For some reason the menu icon doesn't show at all.

Code: https://gist.github.com/VlatkoStojkoski/290234f49a6f4e51019ca4b014c03f37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong css selector in media query.

add this to @media screen and (max-width: 775px).

```
nav .burger {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: In SCSS its also possible to write @media(max-width: 780px).   If you meant that

Comment: yes write where is css selector .burger that need to change to nav .burger

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set `display: none` to the menu. Even though you added a media query with `display: block` on the bottom, the first one will always rule.

You should add a media query to the first rule and you can remove the `display: block` on the bottom.

```css
.burger {
  @media screen and (min-width: 775px) { 
    display: none;
  }
}
```

So this is your complete code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap");
$text-color: whitesmoke;
$font-stack: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
$nav-color: rgba(79, 91, 102, 0.8);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 12vh;
  font-family: $font-stack;
  background-color: $nav-color;
  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: $text-color;
  }
  img {
    width: 64px;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 35%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    a {
      font-size: 21px;
      color: $text-color;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
  }
  .burger {
    @media screen and (min-width: 775px) { 
      display: none;
    }

    div {
      width: 30px;
      height: 4px;
      background-color: $text-color;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  nav ul {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 775px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 88vh;
    top: 12vh;
    background-color: $nav-color;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    li {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```